# strpos(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack) of type string is deprecated

Tags: magento2, php8

I am getting error with Magento 2.4.4 & 2.4.5

Here is my line of code

```
<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ? $position : ''; ?>>
```

Answer (score 4):

In Magento 2.4.4 was changed some important logic in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml`

1. `getProductDetailsHtml` renders for non saleable products
2. Added options logic

```php
                                            <?php $options = $block->getData('viewModel')->getOptionsData($_product); ?>
                                            <?php foreach ($options as $optionItem): ?>
                                                <input type="hidden"
                                                       name="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml($optionItem['name']) ?>"
                                                       value="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml($optionItem['value']) ?>">
                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

3. `strpos` to `$pos` to:

```php
                <?= ($pos && strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions')) ?
                /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderStyleAsTag(
                    $position,
                    'product-item-info_' . $_product->getId() . ' div.product-item-actions'
                ) : '' ?>
```

```php
                                <?= ($pos && strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary')) ?
                                    /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderStyleAsTag(
                                        $position,
                                        'product-item-info_' . $_product->getId() . ' div.actions-secondary'
                                    ) : '' ?>
```

4. bottom toolbar renders with:

```php
    <?= $block->getChildBlock('toolbar')->setIsBottom(true)->toHtml() ?>
```

I'm strongly suggest to compare your design file with core file and make related changes

Answer (score 1):

Insted of passing  null in the method strpos() pass an empty string if the variable is null i check the variable first and then use them in code

here is my code

```
<?php //Modifications 29 August 2022 (hassan)
      if(!$pos)
       {
          $pos = '';
       }
       if(!$viewMode)
       {
          $viewMode = '';
       }
  ?>
```

EDIT:

You may also just use the same syntax used on your question, and use `empty()` to make sure your variables are empty or not:

```
$pos = !empty($pos) ? $pos : '';

$viewMode = !empty($viewMode) ? $viewMode : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ?
                                    /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderStyleAsTag(
                                        $position,
                                        'product-item-info_' . $_product->getId() . ' div.actions-primary'
                                    ) : '' ?>
```